# Using Javascript, how do I change text color in a table while hovering over an image?

Tags: javascript, html, css, colors

**EDIT: I've figured it out, I think! But, if you all have ideas on how to achieve this CLEANLY, that would be awesome! I'm new to Javascript lol**

I have an image and a table with text in it. When I hover over that image, I would like SOME of the text (in separate cells) in the table to change colors ON HOVER.

The code below works fine for ONE sticker. However, when I try to change it to class (e.g. class="sticker3") and .getElementsByClassName("sticker3"), it doesn't work.

```
<span id="sticker3" style="font-size: 30px;margin:0px;line-height:0px;color:#000000;">✿</span>
```

```
<script>
        function upDate(){
            document.getElementById('sticker3').style.color = "#FF0000";
    }
    
        function unDo(){
            X = document.getElementById('sticker3');
            X.style.color = "";
            document.getElementById('sticker3').style.color = "FFFFFF";
    }
    </script>
```

When I tried to change the code to this, it stops working.

```
<span class="sticker3" style="font-size: 30px;margin:0px;line-height:0px;color:#000000;">✿</span>
```

```
<script>
        function upDate(){
            document.getElementsByClassName('sticker3').style.color = "#FF0000";
    }
    
        function unDo(){
            X = document.getElementsByClassName('sticker3');
            X.style.color = "";
            document.getElementsByClassName('sticker3').style.color = "FFFFFF";
    }
    </script>
```

Attached an image to help explain what I'm trying to achieve. You can see that only one flower is red when hovering over image 1, but I want all of the flowers in that column to be red.
[IMAGE HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hnnqT.png)

**Code Snippet**

```js
function upDate() {
  document.getElementsByClassName('sticker3').style.color = "#FF0000";
}

function unDo() {
  X = document.getElementsByClassName('sticker3');
  X.style.color = "";
  document.getElementsByClassName('sticker3').style.color = "FFFFFF";
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td,
th {
  border: thin solid lightgray;
  padding: 0.2rem;
}

.sticker3:after {
  content: "✿";
  font-size: 20px;
  margin: 0px;
  line-height: 0px;
  color: #000000;
}

.hoverbox {
  width: 10rem;
  display: inline-block;
  border: thin solid gray;
  background-color: lightyellow;
  margin: 0.5rem;
  padding: 0.5rem;
}
```

```html
<table id="table1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Fig 1</th>
      <th>Fig 2</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td><span class="sticker3"></span></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td><span class="sticker3"></span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td><span class="sticker3"></span></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td><span class="sticker3"></span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td><span class="sticker3"></span></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td><span class="sticker3"></span></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>

</table>

<div id="hover1" class="hoverbox">Fig 1 Hover</div>
<div id="hover2" class="hoverbox">Fig 2 Hover</div>
```

Comment: Added an image!

Answer (score 1):

You are not addressing the collection returned by the method...

maybe try:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('sticker3')[0];
```